# how to proritize UDP port in tc

Tags: udp, traffic-shaping, tc, raspbian

I have this TC code

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dport xxxx 0xffff flowid 1:1
```

where XXXX is the port number.

I know that this is for TCP. how can I achieve this for UDP?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

... sorry, you match all ip port (TCP and UDP)

If you want to match only TCP or UDP you need to add the protocol number

```
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dport xxxx 0xffff match ip protocol 6 0xff flowid 1:1
```

For UDP:

```
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dport xxxx 0xffff match ip protocol 17 0xff flowid 1:1
```